# What is the difference between $X/A$ and $X\setminus A$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $A\subset X$. What is the difference between $X/A$ and $X\setminus A$? It seems to be that they're exactly the same, except for the fact that in $X/A$ the whole of $A$ has been reduced to a point, while in $X\setminus A$, $A$ has completely been removed.

Thanks

Comment: Everything's exactly the same to $\rm foo$, except for the fact that... it isn't. 
Compare $D^1/S^1 = S^2$ and $D^1\smallsetminus S^1=\operatorname{int}(D^1)$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff- Yes I think I see the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Too see how topologically different $X/A$ and $X\setminus A$ can be, let $X=\mathbb{S}^1$, $\theta\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $A=\{e^{in\theta};n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

- $X/A$ is [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space) as a continuous mapping of $X$, while $X\setminus A$ is not.
- $X/A$ is [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) as a continuous mapping of $X$, while $X\setminus A$ is [totally disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space).
- $X\setminus A$ is [Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space), while $X/A$ is not.